# Removing object from ArrayList using equality

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to remove a card from a deck of cards if 2 values are equal to each other. The equality is detecting whether or not the 2 values are matching (explained in the code) but I can't figure out how to remove the 2nd to last card in the array if it matches.

```
    private void makeMovePreviousPile(){
    int lastDealtCardPos = theFlop.size() - 1; //allows us to see how many cards have been dealt, are you even trying to challenge us Chris?
    int previouslyDealtCardPos = lastDealtCardPos - 1;

    if(lastDealtCardPos != 0){ // check that the deck has been shuffled
        String lastDealtCardValue = theFlop.get(lastDealtCardPos).getValue(); // fetches the value of the last dealt card
        String lastDealtCardSuit = theFlop.get(lastDealtCardPos).getSuit(); // fetches the suit of the last dealt card
        String previouslyDealtCardValue = theFlop.get(previouslyDealtCardPos).getValue(); // fetches the 2nd to last dealt card's value
        String previouslyDealtCardSuit = theFlop.get(previouslyDealtCardPos).getSuit(); // fetches the 2nd to last dealt card's suit

        if(lastDealtCardValue.equals(previouslyDealtCardValue)){
            theFlop.remove(previouslyDealtCardValue);
        }
        else if(lastDealtCardSuit.equals(previouslyDealtCardSuit)) {
            theFlop.remove(previouslyDealtCardSuit);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Cannot make a move. Are you sure you know the rules?");
        }
        printCardsFromFlop();
        //System.out.print(lastDealtCardValue + "\n");
    }
    else { // if it hasn't been shuffled we shun the user.
        System.out.println("Are you sure you shuffled the deck before dealing? Stop trying to cheat.");
        System.out.println("Next time we play Monopoly you won't be the banker. \n");
    }
    //System.out.print(totalDealtCards + " "); // should be equal to the amount of cards we've dealt, if not we've got a problem Huston.
    System.out.print("Total cards on the flop: " + lastDealtCardPos + " "); // checking to see that its working as intended
    //System.out.print("Previous card dealt: " + previouslyDealtCardPos);
}
```

This method checks via .equals to see whether or not one of the two characteristics a card can have match (suit is the same between 2 or the number is the same between the two). If they match, theFlop.remove(previouslyDealtCard) should remove the card completely from the array and the most recently dealt card takes its position in the array.

Can anybody offer some guidance as to how I should be removing the matching card?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide a small, runnable program that displays the problem you're having. What you've given is not enough to answer.

Comment: did you make yourself familiar with [collections API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)?

Comment: @Gene the code has all the hints, `Next time we play Monopoly...` piece is especially helpful to understand teh issue ;)

Comment: @harshtuna Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: well, if @Jay was capable to produce this mcve, he would not have asked the question. I bet you also see where the bug was. At this level of java asking for mcve is kind of trolling :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently collection `theFlop` is something like `List<Card>`, removing `String` will always return false.
Try

```
final Card lastDealtCard = theFlop.get(lastDealtCardPos);
...
if (lastDealtCard.getValue().equals(previouslyDealtCard.getValue())) {
    theFlop.remove(previouslyDealtCard);
}
```